# Non-Kantian answers to the Kantian question of representation

Tags: reference-request, kant, analytic-philosophy

In his book “Kant and the Foundations of Analytic Philosophy” Robert Hanna says that the central concern of Kant’s Critique of Pure Reason is to answer the question of “how can the same judgment be at once necessarily true, related to the real or natural world in a substantive way, yet cognizable by creatures minded like us apart from sensory experience?” Shortly thereafter Hanna rephrases this as: “How are objective mental representations possible?”

What are some books/papers by analytic philosophers trying to answer this question or similar ones? I’m curious how western philosophers since Kant have addressed this issue.

Comment: Not only the answers but also the question itself evolved. Analytic philosophers are no longer seeking "necessarily true" in the strong sense that Kant and other classics had in mind, they settle for something more pragmatic and relativized to historical 'paradigms'. For a post-Kantian take on the interplay between empirical and *a priori* see e.g. [Friedman's book Dynamics of Reason](https://web.stanford.edu/group/cslipublications/cslipublications/pdf/1575862921.pdf).

Comment: I find this question a bit problematic.....on one hand, it is quite straightforward, on the other hand, it is highly subjective and ends in lists of 'favourites'. For example, Tim Button's *The Limits of Realism* shows, built upon Putnam, that no traditional argument establishing the objectivity of representations is coherent. This makes pragmatist philosophy and some lesser known positions (like Plessner) much more appealing. But none of them are analytic. The beauty of Button's book is that it shows analytically that there is no rigurous, coherent analytic philosophy on that matter.

Comment: Indeed contemporary analytic philosophy confirms the Kantian objective transcendental nature of most of our natural languages evolved (inter)subjectively when they're understood and expressed *felicitously*, while OTOH empirical sensory experience from cognizable creatures minded like us is always contingently idiosyncratic as there're no two identical leafs in this contingent world, thus this sounds like one of the central puzzles and problems intrigued by scientists and especially philosophers for a long time... Can we unintuitively publicly share some (or all) ideas fully objectively?...

Answer (score 1):

This is in some contexts called **[the symbol-grounding problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_grounding_problem)**. In a philosophical setting, we could call it the **problem of objective purport** or **problem of intentionality**. Various people after Kant have attempted to explore alternative answers to one that Kant provided and tried to extent the answer that Kant had already provided. Davidson's [theory of interpretation](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/davidson/#RadiInte) or Husserl's [phenomenology](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/phenomenology/) can be seen as such attempts, adopting varying (perhaps complementary, cf. Dagfinn Føllesdal, *Meaning and Experience*) perspectives.

As for some books from analytic philosophers:

1. Bas van Fraasen, *Scientific Representation: Paradoxes of Perspective*
2. Donald Davidson, *Inquiries into Truth and Interpretation*
3. Ian Hacking,  *Historical Ontology*
4. Robert Brandom, *Making it Explicit* (or *Articulating Reasons*)
5. Hilary Putnam, *The Meaning of "Meaning"*
6. And, as someone mentioned in the comments, Michael Friedman, *Dynamics of Reason*